# svg - get path coordinates of overlapping shape areas

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

For overlapping svg shapes, is it possible to get the path coordinates of the overlapped areas?

[This intersection library](http://www.kevlindev.com/geometry/2D/intersections/index.htm) shows the points of the intersecting **lines**, but I"m after the path of the entire **shape** that is the overlapped area ([the brown area here](http://www.kevlindev.com/geometry/2D/intersections/intersect_ellipse_ellipse.svg)).

Ultimately I want to overlap up to 5 shapes and then have each overlap area able to have a hover state that changes its color and adds a tooltip [like this example](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/general-election-2015/politics-blog/11497669/Every-single-possible-coalition-and-post-election-power-sharing-deal-in-one-chart.html). Here, if you *inspect element* on one of the overlap areas, you can see that first, full ellipses were drawn with opacity to create the **visual representation** of overlaps.
`<g id="Main_x5F_Diagram">` But then, there is a following group that has the **actual** overlap areas themselves.
`<g id="Rollover_x5F_area">`

One thought is to draw the main shapes in Illustrator, then use its Pathfinder tools to Intersect or Divide them into separate overlaps areas. Then for each new overlap area, *Save As* .svg to get its path coordinates, then clean that up and bring it into D3.

But, of course, I would much prefer just to draw the shapes in D3 and use some calculation or library to get the overlapped areas without going through the Illustrator exercise. I hope I'm just unaware of some tool, or property or function called getIntersectedAreaPathCoordinatesPlease :)

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I found your question interesting for my own purpose so I did a little research on the web.

I found [this website](http://apike.ca/prog_svg_clip.html) that explains how to use clipping in SVG, and guess what, it can intersect (cf. ***Intersection and Union***)

> [image: different clipping shapes]

Basically you'll need to create a clip-path having both shapes intersect and apply it to one of them. Sadly, the article says :

> There is no direct way to intersect 3 or more clipping paths.

But the "direct" word make me feel confident that you should find a way through your problem :)

**EDIT: Added a modified version of the source to illustrate overlapping and hover behaviour.**

```css
rect:hover {
  fill: red
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve"
         width="200" height="200"
         viewBox="0 0 200 200"  >
 
 <!-- Matthew Bystedt http://apike.ca 2012 -->
 
 <!-- Pattern Definition -->
 <defs>
  <pattern id="checkerPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
    x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20"
    viewBox="0 0 10 10" >
    
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="5" height="5" fill="lightblue" />
   <rect x="5" y="5" width="5" height="5" fill="lightblue" />
  </pattern>

        <radialGradient id="myFillGrad" r="100%" spreadMethod="reflect">
            <stop offset="5%" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="0.5" />
            <stop offset="95%" stop-color="midnightblue" />
        </radialGradient>
        
        <clipPath id="clip1">
            <polygon id="clip1Shape" points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180 100,10" stroke="blue" />        
        </clipPath>

        <clipPath id="clip2">
            <circle id="clip2Shape" cx="100" cy="100" r="65" />
        </clipPath>
 
        <!-- Union -->
        <clipPath id="clipUnion">
            <use x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" xlink:href="#clip1Shape" />
            <use x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" xlink:href="#clip2Shape" />
        </clipPath>        
    
        <!-- Intersection -->
        <clipPath id="clipIntersection" clip-path="url(#clip1)">
            <use x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" xlink:href="#clip2Shape" />
        </clipPath>

 </defs>

 <!-- Background -->
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#checkerPattern)" />
 
 <!-- Examples -->
    
 <rect x="10" y="10" width="180" height="180" fill="url(#myFillGrad)" clip-path="url(#clip1)" transform="translate(-50)"/>
 <rect x="10" y="10" width="180" height="180" fill="url(#myFillGrad)" clip-path="url(#clip2)" transform="translate(0,-40)"/>
 <rect x="10" y="10" width="180" height="180" fill="url(#myFillGrad)" clip-path="url(#clipIntersection)" transform="translate(50,0)" />
 <rect x="10" y="10" width="180" height="180" fill="url(#myFillGrad)" clip-path="url(#clipUnion)" transform="translate(0,40)" />

    <text x="100" y="95%" fill="black"  font-size="25" text-anchor="middle">overlap</text>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing that site and pasting the examples. It seems the resulting intersection is a rect with a link to the calculated "mask". I'm wondering what would happen upon hover color change and with tooltip positioning. Well, I'll try it out and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, thanks for putting that together, very kind of you. Yes, it seems to work great. I'm going to try it locally and will report back. Thanks!